# How I convert tensoflow Linear(kernel_constraint=max_norm) to pytorch code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

```
Dense(self.latent_dim, kernel_constraint=max_norm(0.5))(en_conv)
```

I want to convert the above tensoflow code to pytorch, but I don't understand kernel_constraint=max_norm(0.5). How can I convert it?

Answer (score -1):

one way possible is to do it by a custom layer that you can use in the model as a custom layer. Kernel constrain is the same as you do by initializing the value in the simple Dense layer.

> Sample: Dense layer with initial weight, you can use tf.zeros() or tf.ones() or random function or tf.constant() but the model training result does not always converge at the single points. To find possibilities you need to initial it from specific but running you may start from trained values.

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Simply Dense
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class SimpleDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, units=32):
      super(SimpleDense, self).__init__()
      self.units = units

  def build(self, input_shape):
      self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                               initializer='random_normal',
                               trainable=True)
      self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,),
                               initializer='random_normal',
                               trainable=True)

  def call(self, inputs):
      return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
```

> Sample: As the question requirements, Dense layer with an initializer of the MaxNorm constrain.

```
import tensorflow as tf

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Funtions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MaxNorm(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, max_value=2, axis=1):
        super(MaxNorm, self).__init__()
        # self.units = units
        self._out_shape = None
        self.max_value = max_value
        self.axis = axis

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self._out_shape = input_shape

    def call(self, inputs):
        temp = tf.keras.layers.Dense(inputs.shape[1], kernel_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.MaxNorm(max_value=self.max_value, axis=self.axis), activation=None)( inputs )

        return temp
        
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Tasks
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""       
temp = tf.constant([[ 0.00346701, -0.00676209, -0.00109781, -0.0005832 ,  0.00047849, 0.00311204,  0.00843922, -0.00400238,  0.00127922, -0.0026469 ,
-0.00232184, -0.00686269,  0.00021552, -0.0039388 ,  0.00753652,
-0.00405236, -0.0008759 ,  0.00275771,  0.00144688, -0.00361056,
-0.0036177 ,  0.00778807, -0.00116923,  0.00012773,  0.00276652,
0.00438983, -0.00769166, -0.00432891, -0.00211244, -0.00594028,
0.01009954,  0.00581804, -0.0062736 , -0.00921499,  0.00710281,
0.00022364,  0.00051054, -0.00204145,  0.00928543, -0.00129213,
-0.00209933, -0.00212295, -0.00452125, -0.00601313, -0.00239222,
0.00663724,  0.00228883,  0.00359715,  0.00090024,  0.01166699,
-0.00281386, -0.00791688,  0.00055902,  0.00070648,  0.00052972,
0.00249906,  0.00491098,  0.00528313, -0.01159694, -0.00370812,
-0.00950641,  0.00408999,  0.00800613,  0.0014898 ]], dtype=tf.float32)

layer = MaxNorm(max_value=2)
print( layer( temp )[0][tf.math.argmax(layer( temp )[0]).numpy()] )
layer = MaxNorm(max_value=4)
print( layer( temp )[0][tf.math.argmax(layer( temp )[0]).numpy()] )
layer = MaxNorm(max_value=10)
print( layer( temp )[0][tf.math.argmax(layer( temp )[0]).numpy()] )
```

> Output: The custom modified creation of a new layer, one way to prove the answer is initial from near zero or where you know about results. Starting from zero you pay attention in less vary but none zeros you do most at the magnitudes of the process.

```
tf.Tensor(-0.8576179, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(0.6010429, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(2.2286513, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: The question is asking how to convert the code into PyTorch, your answer is using TensorFlow. You are not answering the question.

Comment: He wants to convert into PyTorch, question is wants to understand the parameter max norm then I guild him the way the initial variable for the Dense layer could create more functions and initial values. My answer is on target of his question he want to explain the parameter and I create example.

https://neptune.ai/blog/moving-from-tensorflow-to-pytorch

Comment: Come on... do you really expect anyone to believe that? This is just wrapping a call to Tensorflow's MaxNorm function. It doesn't show anything about implementing it, much less in PyTorch.